# Adsense revenue depending on use of Ajax

Tags: ajax, adsense

I noticed that a website like imgur.com displays ads on each page of the website.
This means each time you press "next" to view another funny picture, AdSense refreshes.

But a website where you can scroll to view more pages(such as 9gag.com),
Ajax handles loading of more funny pictures so it's illegal to refresh Adsense when a user scrolls for more funny pictures.

Does this means 50 users staying on 9gag.com for 3 hours scrolling and viewing 300 funny pictures would help 9gag.com generate revenue equal to ONE imgur.com user that views only 1 picture?

Does this also mean I should stay away from Ajax if I wanted revenue?

This was very confusing for me, please help me understand AdSense better.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WEll the problem with fully scripted ajax loaded content is that Adsense cannot read it. Therefore it has a hard time displaying relevant ads, because most advertisers have chosen to target the visitor location and the keywords on the pages. So if Adsense has no text, then most of the time it's not going to be able to serve an ad.

But I looked at 9gag.com and they are using what I think is the ajax version of Adsense, or perhaps the premium version of Adsense which allows for all sorts of things and is quite different from the core Adsense program in many ways that nobody seems to know about, and few are invited. All the big publishers I suppose.

Anyway, if you do end up clicking on one of the posts on 9gag.com you'll see other ads. Granted that the way that imgr.com has things set up should encourage more content viewing per visitor and thus also some more ad viewing, but I wouldn't say that one necessarily has more traffic overall than the other. There are too many unknown factors to determine that. Not something you can do just with looking at a site. That is where having good analytics of your traffic and visitor behavior comes in.

Comment: Thank you! Like you said, they do have more content viewing per visitor for imgur. I would assume that this is the reason 9gag.com was holding back from changing into an ajax on the fly loading.
I can guess that 9gag had contacted google about this too.
Thank you for your knowledge, much appreciated. Sorry I answered late :P